# How to put an overlay over normal layout

Tags: android, android-layout, flappy-bird-clone

I'm doing a mini game just by using a linear layout with buttons and textfields. I want to have an overlay like the highscore overlay in flappy bird:

[image]

(the orange box in the middle)

Are there any ways to get this without converting my current layout into a canvas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `LinearLayout` to a  `RelativeLayout`. Make the overlay default as invisible, then use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the overlay when you want it to show.

Comment: And what does this overlay (the box) consists of then ?

Comment: you could make it another RelativeLayout, with all your imageviews and text and buttons inside it

Comment: where my overlay is supposed to be are other buttons and stuff right now, which I don't want to be moved aside when the overlay shows up

Comment: That's why you need RelativeLayout as your top ViewGroup. Positioning views in a RelativeLayout will just place them on top of the other views unless attributes like `android:layout_below` are set.

Comment: As my top ViewGroup ? I don't understand. My app was like this: http://i.imgur.com/FWyE4cN.png  And I change it to this: http://i.imgur.com/l99EtGZ.png  My testbutton is invisible though

Comment: Yes you're getting the idea. The testbutton is invisible because of the Z order. Put it below the LinearLayout and it should show up. Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to center it. Then you can change the testbutton to a RelativeLayout or another LinearLayout and make an overlay.